# Having Interceptor Read Cached Value

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to have my interceptor read from my cache to see if a post request has been cached already when I am offline. If so, I would return the cached local data instead and display it. The cache is using the Ionic storage cache.

In this example, I just have one url pattern (api/dfrs/id) getting  checked and I have that value cached.  I am looping through the cache and getting the value if a certain key is set. Each cache value is the post request itself.

The value is eventually found, but since the method to get the value is async, the interceptor code continues on before the cached result is returned.

So two problems I am trying to solve

1) Have the code in the first if statement run on that promise method

2) Return the body of the cached request as an Observable so my view can use it

Any help would be super appreciated. Thanks

token.interceptor

`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError, BehaviorSubject, from, EMPTY, NEVER, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, filter, take, switchMap, finalize, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../admin/users/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage, IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { CacheSaveDataService } from './cache-save-data.service';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  private isRefreshing = false;
  private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

  constructor(public authService: AuthService, public cacheSaveDataService: CacheSaveDataService) { }

 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (!this.cacheSaveDataService.status.connected && request.method === 'GET' &&
      request.url.indexOf('api/dfrs/id/') !== -1) {
      return next.handle(request).pipe (
        map((event: any) => {
          let val = this.getCachedResult(request);
          return (Observable.create(val));
        })
      )

    } else if (!this.cacheSaveDataService.status.connected && request.url.indexOf('authenticate') === -1
      && request.url.indexOf('logout') === -1  && (request.method === 'PUT' || request.method === 'POST')) {

      const result = this.cacheSaveDataService.setStorageRequest(request);

      return next.handle(request).pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                console.log('event--->>>', event);
            }
            return event;
        }),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            let data = {};
            data = {
                reason: error && error.error && error.error.reason ? error.error.reason : '',
                status: error.status
            };
            return throwError(error);
        }));

    } else {
      const userId = this.getUserId();
      if (this.authService.getJwtToken()) {
        request = this.addToken(request, this.authService.getJwtToken(), userId);
      }

      return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse && error.status === 401) {
          return this.handle401Error(request, next);
        } else {
            if (error.status === 405) { //|| error.status === 500) {
              this.authService.backToLogin();
            }
          console.log('error, not logged in');
          return throwError(error);
        }
      }));
    }
    console.log ('Done Intercepter');
  }

  async getCachedResult(request) {
    const keys = await this.cacheSaveDataService.getKeys();
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      const key = keys[i];
      if (key.indexOf('reqcache') !== -1) {
        return  await this.getKeyValue(key, request);
      }
    }
  }

  async getKeyValue(key, request) {
    const res = await this.cacheSaveDataService.get2(key);
    const val: any = res;

    if (val.url === request.url) {
      return val;
    }
  }

  private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string, userId: string) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
      'userId': userId
    });
    return request.clone({headers});
  }

  private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const userId = this.getUserId();
    if (!this.isRefreshing) {
      this.isRefreshing = true;
      this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

      return this.authService.refreshToken().pipe(
        switchMap((token: any) => {
          this.isRefreshing = false;
          this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.jwt);
          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.jwt, userId));
        }));

    } else {
      return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
        filter(token => token != null),
        take(1),
        switchMap(jwt => {
          return next.handle(this.addToken(request, jwt, userId));
        }));
    }
  }

  private getUserId() {
    const user: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user') );
    let userId = '0';
    if (user !== undefined && user !== null) {
      userId = user._id;
    }
    return userId;
  }

}
```

`

cache-save-data.service.ts
`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage, IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Network } from '@capacitor/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SharedService } from '../shared/shared.service';
import { DFRPhotoService } from '../dfr/daily-summary/dfr-photo/dfr-photo.service';
import { LoadingController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CacheSaveDataService {

  status = null;
  handler;
  loaderElement;

  constructor(
      public storage: Storage,
      private httpClient: HttpClient,
      private sharedService: SharedService,
      private loadingController: LoadingController) {

    this.status = this.getStatus();
    if (this.handler === undefined) {
      console.log('Add Listener ', status);
      this.handler = Network.addListener('networkStatusChange', (status) => {
        console.log('Network status changed! ', status);
        const oldStatus = this.status;
        this.status = status;
        if (this.status.connected && !oldStatus.connected) {
          this.saveCachedData();
        }
        this.status = status;
        if (!this.status.connected) {
          this.sharedService.showNotification('Network connection has terminated.', 'danger', 5000);
        }
      });
    }
  }



  public async setItem(key, value) {
    return await this.storage.set(key, value);
  }

  public async setStorageRequest2(request) {
    const cacheKey = 'reqcache-' + this.sharedService.generateId();
    return await this.storage.set(cacheKey, request);
  }

  public async setStorageRequest(request) {
    this.sharedService.showNotification('User is offline. Service Request Cached', 'warning', 2000);
    const cacheKey = 'reqcache-' + this.sharedService.generateId() + '-' + request.urlWithParams;
    return await this.storage.set(cacheKey, request);
  }

  public async get(settingName){
    return await this.storage.get(`setting:${ settingName }`);
  }

  public async get2(settingName) {
    return await this.storage.get(settingName);
  }

  public async remove(settingName){
    return await this.storage.remove(settingName);
  }

  public clear() {
    this.storage.clear().then(() => {
      console.log('all keys cleared');
    });
  }

  public async getKeys() {
    return await this.storage.keys();
  }

  public async getStatus() {
    this.status = await Network.getStatus();
  }


}
```

`

//dfr.service.ts (method in class only)
`

```
public getDFRByDfrId(id: string) {
    return this.httpClient.get(environment.apiURL + this.path + '/id/' + id)
    .pipe(
      map((res: any) => {
        return res.data;
      })
    );
  }
```

`

// view.ts (subscribing only)
`

```
   this.dfrService.getDFRByDfrId(paramMap.get('id')).subscribe(val => {
               this.currentDFR = val;
            });
```

`

I am expecting the body of my cached request to be returned

Comment: OK well I got the first part solved by using from and switchMap as I can see the call getting completed after the promise.

EG: something like this

 return from(this.getCachedResult(request)).pipe (
          switchMap(data => {
             return next.handle(Observable.create(data))
            //return next.handle(request)
          })
        )

Now I just need to return the data in the cached request as an Observable

Answer (score 0):

LOL finally got it. I was unable to listen to the promise and then has to return an observable.  Hopefully this will help someone ;0

replace this code

```
return next.handle(request).pipe (
    map((event: any) => {
      let val = this.getCachedResult(request);
      return (Observable.create(val));
    })
  )
```

with

```
return from(this.getCachedResult(request)).pipe (
      mergeMap(data => {
         return of(new HttpResponse({ body: data.body }))
      })
    )
```